# Jmeter- How many sample requests are created with this config?

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

I have a question related to JMeter, I have thread with config below:

- Number of Threads (Users): 5
- Ram-Up Period (In second): 5
- Loop: Forever
- Duration(seconds): 2

How many sample request are created with above config ?

I am using the JMeter version 5.0.

Answer (score 2):

We don't know. It mostly depends on **your application response time** which is the main factor of [Elapsed Time](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/glossary.html) in JMeter.

The only way to get the number is to **measure it**

1. [Run your test in command-line non-GUI mode as](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/dear-abby-blazemeter-how-do-i-run-jmeter-non-gui-mode):

   ```
   jmeter -n -t your-test.jmx -l result.jtl
   ```
2. Once test is finished open JMeter GUI, add a [Listener](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#listeners) of your choice, i.e. [Aggregate Report](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Aggregate_Report) to your Test Plan and open `result.jtl` file using "Browse" button - you should see the number of executed samplers as well as other metrics (response time, throughput, latency, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

No of Threads=5 and Ramp up time =5 seconds.
So after every 1 second, next thread will be active.
So ideally it will process maximum 3 samples.

In jmeter Summary report, you could check the sample  requests.